# Active Directory Authentication Error for SQL Server SSDT Unit Tests

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing, sql-server-data-tools

I am using a SSDT unit test project to test procedures on an Azure SQL Server. When I choose SQL Server authentication with a generic login for my server, I can connect no problems. However, when I choose Active Directory Interactive Authentication (the only AAD option available within my organisation and how I normally log in using Visual Studio or SSMS) and I try to run the unit tests, the test window shows the error 'System.ArgumentException: Cannot find an authentication provider for 'ActiveDirectoryInteractive'. Does anyone know how to fix this?

The connection string within my app.config is unchanged from the defaults provided to me.

```
ConnectionString="Data Source=[myserver].database.windows.net;
Initial Catalog=[myDatabase];
Persist Security Info=False;
User ID=[myEmail];
Pooling=False;
MultipleActiveResultSets=False;
Connect Timeout=60;
Encrypt=True;
TrustServerCertificate=False;
Authentication=&quot;Active Directory Interactive&quot;"
```

Comment: Would love to know this as well. Without setting up ODBC.